# float right without defining width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following html

```
<h2>OUR CHAIRMAN</h2>
<div class="profile">
<div class="fleft"><img class="mgmt fleft" src="images/kishan.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></div>
<div class="fright">
<h5>KISHAN LAL DUGAR</h5>
Mr Kishan Lal Dugar, an experienced entrepreneur and visionary, is the founder of the KL Dugar Group. He has steered the Group to the success it enjoys today. His vision led to the diversification and conglomeration of the Group. His meticulous efforts and foresight lead the Group to reach a turnover of over NRs 6,000 million and build up a workforce of over 800 employees.</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.fleft{
    float: left;

}
.fright{
    float: right;
}
```

And to the `fright class` if I define the width then only it goes to right otherwise it goes to downwards. How can I achieve this without defining the width of `.fright`?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGg6H/)

Comment: if you define the width for .fright for eg. 200px then it goes to right that is floated to right but it's not floating to right without defining it

Comment: You can try to remove float property from "fright".

Comment: That's because a DIV will automatically fill the width available. You need to define some sort of width on it for it to look like it's floated right, however maybe what you are after is text-align right within that div so the text runs up against it's right edge?

Comment: No need the `float:right` instead give some padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to go a bit detail on this one, why it happens, and you shouldn't be redundant to add `width` to your element.

Whenever you `float` any element, it will act as if it's an `inline-block` level element, and hence, it will create a gutter/empty space on the other side unused. This will result the element rendering below to shift besides the floated element, unless and until the element is `inline-block`, `inline` or `floated`. Here, you have a `div` which want to `float: right;`, well, it is floated, but it's a block level element by default, a `block` level element will behave like a `inline-block` element, though, there's a catch here, it will take up **ENTIRE** horizontal space, thus it shifts below the floated element(though the element itself is `floated` to the `right`).

Now simple solution here is don't assign `float: right;` to the element at all, it will simply wrap the text around the floated element, whats the bad point here? I'll show you pictorically..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xArrH/1/) (This is dirty yea)

[image]

So you don't want your element to wrap the text below the image, so the workaround is to provide a `margin-left` property to the content block and than you will get something like this..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xArrH/)

```
.fright{
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

[image]

---

> Conclusion: Using `margin` is no bad, I would still suggest you to use
>   `width` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for something similar to this.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KGg6H/5/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.fright {
    display: inline;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to .fright does the trick.

**Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KGg6H/7/**

Answer (score 0):

lots of ways to resolve and the way you do it could be decided on other code and styling used elsewhere.  This is what I used on your demo

```
.fright{
    right: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```